# Bootstrap 3 Mobile nav won collapse when you click outside it

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile-navbar

My Bootstrap 3 mobile menu does collapse when I click/touch outside the menu.

Ive can up with a solution to the problem:

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', 'html:not(nav)',function() {
 $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("in");
});
```

However this doesn't collapse the same way as if you were to click the menu button. Please can somebody recommend a better solution.

Cheers
Al

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
})
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/63158)

Comment: Will this work on mobile (iphone)? I think we need touchstart as well.

Comment: @Marek yes you might need to do `'click touch'` or `'click touchstart'` to make it behave as you need on iOS (I'm unable to test this though)